# I am trying to get the IP addresses of two VM machines from my host machine which is a linux (Kali). How do I find the other 2 machines' IP address?

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, kali-linux

Apologies in advance as this is quite a noob question. I'm trying to find the ip addresses of two virtual machines in from my other virtual host which Kali Linux. I have tried the ip addr and the ifconfig commands but I'm only getting what I believe to be my own IP and not the other two target machines. What would be the right command or approach or tool to use? Appreciate the help and thank you all in advance.

Comment: Go to each machine (host as well) and run ifconfig on all of them. Likely the networking is NAT (default) and the guest machines will all have the same subnet (first 3 octets) and the last one will differ and be unique by guest machine.

Comment: Or `ip addr` if you're using the newer iproute tools rather than `ifconfig` from the older net-tools. These are similar to the Windows command `ipconfig`. If you have a machine on the same subnet as the VMs, you could use nmap on another machine to scan the subnet to reveal the VM IPs: e.g. `nmap -Pn 192.168.1.0/24`

Answer (score 2):

Ok firstly, this depends on how you've setup your virtual machines.
I've done this before but this works for bridged connections. You said your host is KALI, great.

By setting your virtual machines to use a bridged connection, they appear on you network as their own separate connections, meaning you can scan your local net to find their IP Addresses.

arp-scan will give you a list of all connected devices on your localnet

```
sudo arp-scan --localnet
```

or simply use nmap on your local network
first use ifconfig on kali to get your local ip usually (192.168.###.###)
then on nmap

```
nmap 192.168.***.1-255
```